# Can Document AI OCR Processor extract tables?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud-document-ai

I swear I read somewhere that v1beta3 of the OCR Processor could do table extraction. I tested using the 2020 and 2022 version and have had no table data being returned. Did I just imagine what I read or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For detecting and extracting data from tables, use the [Form Parser processor](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/processors-list#processor_form-parser)

And it's recommended to use the `v1` API for production applications rather than `v1beta3` or `v1beta2`

[Which Processor should I use?](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/overview#which-processor:%7E:text=Extract-,tables,-or%20key%2Dvalue)

[Handle the processing response - Forms and Tables](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/handle-response#forms_and_tables)

[General Processors Videos & Labs](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/videos#general_processors_in)

Comment: I always wondered what service version was the latest - to me, v1beta3 could read as the beta 3 *before* v1, making the betas obsolete. Since there are still around, it's different. Is there public doc on what's different between the versions ?

Comment: You can check out the REST API references for the methods/resources for each version https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/reference/rest

`v1` is the Generally Available version, whereas `v1beta3` is a Preview version. Some newer features might be pushed to `v1beta3` before `v1`. However, I agree that the naming convention has been confusing because `v1beta3` did come out before `v1` initially.